# Maven Junit 5, Cucumber not running tests

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, cucumber, junit5

When executing my runner, or running my .feature file, no tests are ran via cucumber (same with mvn clean install, mvn clean test etc).
The rest of my program runs completely as expected, and this is an issue I've been gruelling with for a while now.

Result from IntelliJ IDE When I run my runner class :
[image: IDE Result]

Folder Structure:

[image: Folder Structure]

My full pom is like so:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>IE2ETest</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <junit-jupiter.version>5.7.2</junit-jupiter.version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.22.2</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    <cucumber.version>6.10.4</cucumber.version>
    <selenium-jupiter.version>3.4.0</selenium-jupiter.version>

    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>

    <project.enconding>UTF-8</project.enconding>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>${project.enconding}</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>${project.enconding}</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium-jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <configurationParameters>
                        cucumber.plugin=pretty,html:target/site/cucumber-pretty.html
                        cucumber.publish.quiet=true
                        cucumber.publish.enabled=false
                    </configurationParameters>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

RunnerTest.java:

```
package cucumberTests;

import io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Cucumber;

@Cucumber
public class RunnerTest {

}
```

StepDefinitions.java:

```
package cucumberTests.steps;

import helperpackage.Car;
import io.cucumber.java.en.And;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import pomPages.CarTaxHomePage;
import pomPages.FreeCheckPage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.CsvSource;
public class StepDefinitions {
        String drivePath = "./src/test/drivers/chromedriver.exe";
        String currentUrl;
        WebDriver driver;
        CarTaxHomePage homePage;
        FreeCheckPage freePage;

        @Given("Valid Registration value of {string}")
        public void checkReg(String reg){
            assertTrue(Car.isValid(reg));
        }

        @When("the website {string} is live")
        public void openSite(String url) throws IOException {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", drivePath);
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get("https://"+url+"/");
        }

        @And("user enters value of {string}")
        public void enterText(String reg) throws InterruptedException {
            homePage = new CarTaxHomePage(driver);
            Thread.sleep(500);
            homePage.editText(reg);
        }

        @And("user clicks on the free option")
        public void clickSubmit(){
            homePage.clickFreeCheck();
        }

        @Then("user should be taken to the {string} page")
        public void checkPage(String url){
            freePage = new FreeCheckPage(driver);
            String currentUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl();
            String regex = "^(https:\\/\\/"+url +"\\/)";
            String x  = "^(https:\\/\\/" + url +  "?\\S+)";
            if (!currentUrl.matches(regex)){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad link");
            };
        }

        @And("Number plate {string} Should appear")
        public void checkResults(String plate, String make){
            String plateReturned = freePage.getRegReturned();
            String makeReturned = freePage.getMakeReturned();
            if (plateReturned.equals(plateReturned) && makeReturned.equals(make)){
                //
            }else{
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrongfully returned");
            }
        }






    }
```

My IDE Shows that these steps are referenced in another class, as Cucumber doesn't complain about finding the path to features, I'm currently at a loss.
StepDefinitions.feature

```
  Feature: Check tax on car
  Scenario : User enters a valid Reg number and clicks the free check option
    Given Valid Registration value of "LT09YJJ"
    When the website "check.co.uk" is live
    And user enters value of "9YJJ"
    And user clicks on the free option
    Then user should be taken to the "taxcheck.co.uk/hello" page
    And Number plate "9YJJ" Should appear
```

My Cucumber.properties

```
cucumber.publish.enabled=true
```

Comment: Other the `junit-jupiter-params` having the wrong version I don't see any problems. You could debug `io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.DiscoverySelectorResolver` and see what happens.

Comment: Some of the dependencies that you use in StepsDefenitions are unresolved. Please create an issue at the YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA providing a little sample project where the case can be reproduced. Thank you